# Netty channelActive not working when adding handler from other

Tags: java, netty

I have a `AuthenticationHandler extends ChannelHandlerAdapter` and in the `channelRead` a check if the user is valid. If so, i add a new handler (`ServerHandler`) to recive all other messages.

```
ctx.pipeline().addLast(new ServerHandler());
ctx.pipeline().remove(this);
```

The problem is, that the `channelActive` mehod is not executed. But i need this to add the client to a list with all clients. Is there an other way to do this? Maybe someone can help! Is the problem that I'm using Netty 5.0.0 Alpha 2? But this should work, does it?

Answer (score 2):

`channelActive` is only executed when the `Channel` becomes active, which in terms of TCP means when the connection was established. If you add a `ChannelHandler` after the Channel was connected it will not see the active event anymore.

Better override `handlerAdded(...)` which is guaranteed to be called in all cases.